# What should I enter as "Database file" for a SQLite database?

Tags: database, 8, installation

So I've practiced making Drupal 7 before using XAMPP and I want to try to make a Drupal 8 page but I have no clue about what to put in the field you can see in the picture below. I made a database in PHPmyadmin.

[image]

What should I enter in the *Database file* field?

Answer (score 4):

This configuration dialog is for SQLite-type databases only, it might be that your installation only has activated the PHP modules for this type of databases (for MySQL databases, you need pdo-sql, see here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2219779).

If you wish to use a SQLite database (which should work fine for testing purposes), you can either indicate a location for your SQLite database file, or leave the default, which should work fine. The Drupal installer will create the SQLite database for you in that location; you don't need to create it separately.

Comment: I agree, your PHP installation seems to be missing an appropriate mysql integration module.

Comment: I have "PHP Version 7.0.2"

Answer (score 0):

So I got this fixed a while ago by just reinstalling XAMPP. thanks for the help everyone.